# CSS/HTML: Avoid headers being separated from paragraphs

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing

I'm working on a project which deals with printing out HTML-pages onto A4 sheets.

Currently i'm facing the problem that in a print-preview/a generated pdf the headers of some paragraphs floats alone and are not 'connected' to the following paragraph. Like this:

[image: Separated Header]

There's an obvious solution for this; wrap all headers and the following a paragraph in a div and style it to page-break-inside:avoid or display:inline-block. Like this:

[image: Page-break-inside:Avoid]

This solution works great, however there's a but.
Wrapping the headers and paragraphs will in certain situations result in unwanted white blank spaces where the paragraph and header are forced to next page, interrupting the float of the text. Like this:

[image: Blank unwanted space]

I've been fiddling with some jquery solution, however i feel that this quickly becomes unstable and dirty.

Any suggestions?

All the best!

Live-links:

http://template01.info/stack/default.html

http://template01.info/stack/inlineblock.html

http://template01.info/stack/pagebreakinside.html

Comment: Have you checked the HTML to see if the floating test, is surrounded by it's own <p> tag?

Comment: Have you tried if `page-break-after:avoid` on the `<hX>` tags does the trick?

Answer (score 3):

Use this style on your headers:

```css
.header {
  page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this solution. No result.
Here's an updated test: http://template01.info/stack/default.html

`<h3 style="page-break-after: avoid; color:red;" id="explore-with-us">Explore with us!</h3>
<p>In this issue, we invite you to explore with us the following questions and issues: How are ongoing.......</p>`
Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue. Using Chrome 39.

Comment: This is the correct answer by the specs. It seems that it does not help in practice. Firefox has no support (a very longstanding bug), IE seems to avoid page breaks after headings by default, and Chrome apparently does not obey the rule. (If it seems to obey, it may be just because it would not break anyway.)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Dang. So you get the correct result. I Run into the issue from latest firefox, and chrome 39.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela thanks for clearing that up. You also noticed this issue? Any leads/workarounds?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the perfect output in both the links other than default.

Comment: aha. That's actually what i tried to point out; in the two other examples besides the default.html, the result is almost perfect. However the downside of these is that you get big 'blank spaces' sometimes (see third illustration).

Comment: @eskimoproverb Yes, I am getting big blank spaces, which are perfectly okay right? You can use CSS to avoid page break after Headings and allow page breaks inside paragraphs?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I would like to avoid the blank spaces. Tried your suggestion, but without luck. Maybe you could help me out. Example at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbgmdp

Comment: @eskimoproverb Sure, I will help you out. Lemme figure out a solution for you... `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Thanks, but please don't spend to much time on it! :)